# How to create custom table field in system.xml of the module

Tags: magento2, admin, system.xml

**Problem**

I need two-column table. First — simple text field and the second should be an image.

**What was done**

Now I have this. The second column should be an image.

[image: desc]

**Code**

```
class Customermap extends \Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray
{


    protected $_customerGroupRenderer;

    protected $_addAfter = false;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory $elementFactory,
        array $data = [ ]
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('field1', [ 'label' => __('Адрес'), 'size' => 300 ]);
        $this->addColumn('customer_group', [
                'label'    => __('Customer Group'),
                'renderer' => $this->_customerGroupRenderer
            ]);


    }

}
```

**Additional information**

Saw one example with something called "GroupRender", but suppose it was wrong. In source files saw some "renders" to transfer in "addColumn" method, but can't understand how to use it.

Comment: What is $this->_customerGroupRenderer holding?

Comment: @AaronAllen for now it holds nothing. I don't know how to create "render for column")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this method to your Customermap class:

```
    protected function getCustomerGroupRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_customerGroupRenderer) {
            $this->_customerGroupRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                'Path\To\CustomerGroup\Element',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }
        return $this->_customerGroupRenderer;
    }
```

'Path\To\CustomerGroup\Element' is a class that will extend AbstractBlock that has the logic for mapping customer groups to images. Use the _toHtml method to specify your image element.

You then change the _prepareToRender method in Customermap to this:

```
    protected function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('field1', [ 'label' => __('Адрес'), 'size' => 300 ]);
        $this->addColumn('customer_group', [
                'label'    => __('Customer Group'),
                'renderer' => $this->getCustomerGroupRenderer()
            ]);


    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've outputted some custom HTML markup, but how can I use standard image downloader? I suppose my *Path\To\CustomerGroup\Element* should extends some class or implement interface, but for now I'm not sure what exactly.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'standard image downloader.'  Blocks have a method `$this->getViewFileUrl('image/foo.jpg') ` that you can use to get the URL of an image file from the static content found under pub/static/frontend/NameSpace/themeName/languageCode/

Comment: I meant something like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6em59ewi4jojzg/Screen%20Shot%202016-07-10%20at%2002.47.29.png?dl=0).

Answer (score 6):

In addition with @Aaron Allen post, if your field `customer_group` is a **select element** you need one more function to retrieve the selection of each field, in `Customermap` class :

```
/**
 * Prepare existing row data object
 *
 * @param DataObject $row
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function _prepareArrayRow(DataObject $row)
{
    $customerGroup = $row->getCustomerGroup();
    $options = [];
    if (!is_null($customerGroup) && $cmsBlock) {
        $options['option_' . $this->getCustomerGroupRenderer()->calcOptionHash($customerGroup)] = 'selected="selected"';
    }
    $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, saved my day